# Combine multiple unique MySQL tables and order by one column, #2

Tags: php, mysql, union

I've got two unique tables, all I'm trying to do is combine the records and sort them by the id (which is unix timestamp):

I used the best matching solution on Internet to write this code (and kept all columns unique for each table): [Combine multiple unique MySQL tables and order by one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534763/combine-multiple-unique-mysql-tables-and-order-by-one-column)

```
$query_ticket_entries = "   SELECT * from (
        SELECT  id AS id, id AS timeentryid, userid AS timeentryuserid,
                serviceid AS timeentryserviceid, servicerateid AS timeentryservicerateid,   
                started AS timeentrystarted, ended AS timeentryended,   
                summary AS timeentrysummary, notes AS timeentrynotes,   
                NULL AS a, NULL AS b, NULL AS c, NULL AS d          
        FROM ticket_time_entries WHERE ticketid = '$ticket_id'
        UNION
        SELECT  id AS id, NULL AS aa, NULL AS bb, NULL AS cc,   
                NULL AS dd, NULL AS ee, NULL AS ff, NULL AS gg,
                NULL AS hh, id AS noteid, userid AS noteuserid,
                typeid AS notetypeid, data AS notedata  
        FROM ticket_notes WHERE ticketid = '$ticket_id'
        ) ticket_entries ORDER BY ticket_entries.id DESC
";
```

I'm getting the following result which is missing all columns in ticket_notes table.

[image: SQL result]

Please help me to identify the issue and have a great weekend. =))

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.6
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Aug 02, 2014 at 08:53 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.38-log
-- PHP Version: 5.5.7

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `ticket_notes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket_notes` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ticketid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `typeid` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `data` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `ticket_time_entries`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket_time_entries` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ticketid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `serviceid` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `servicerateid` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `started` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ended` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `summary` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `notes` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `ticket_notes`
--
ALTER TABLE `ticket_notes`
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `ticket_time_entries`
--
ALTER TABLE `ticket_time_entries`
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: I believe your issue is that your returned row column is `a` not `noteid`. You can either change your query to `NULL AS noteid` in the 1st SELECT, or try `if (is_numeric($row_ticket_entries['a']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION staples resulting rows on top of each other, so all column names from second or subsequent queries comprising UNION aren't going to appear. Are you sure that you need UNION and not JOIN?

```
$query_ticket_entries = " 
        SELECT  tte.id AS timeentryid, tte.userid AS timeentryuserid,
                serviceid AS timeentryserviceid, servicerateid AS timeentryservicerateid,   
                started AS timeentrystarted, ended AS timeentryended,   
                summary AS timeentrysummary, notes AS timeentrynotes,   
                tn.id AS noteid, tn.userid AS noteuserid,
                typeid AS notetypeid, data AS notedata         
        FROM ticket_time_entries tte LEFT JOIN ticket_notes tn
        ON tte.ticketid=tn.ticketid
        WHERE tte.ticketid = '$ticket_id'
        ORDER BY timeentryid DESC
";
```

UPDATE. OK I get what you want to achieve. It seems a bit strange, but nevertheless:

```
$query_ticket_entries = "   SELECT * from (
        SELECT  id AS id, id AS timeentryid, userid AS timeentryuserid,
                serviceid AS timeentryserviceid, servicerateid AS timeentryservicerateid,   
                started AS timeentrystarted, ended AS timeentryended,   
                summary AS timeentrysummary, notes AS timeentrynotes,   
                NULL AS noteid, NULL AS noteuserid, NULL AS notetypeid, NULL AS notedata          
        FROM ticket_time_entries WHERE ticketid = '$ticket_id'
        UNION
        SELECT  id AS id, NULL AS aa, NULL AS bb, NULL AS cc,   
                NULL AS dd, NULL AS ee, NULL AS ff, NULL AS gg,
                NULL AS hh, id AS noteid, userid AS noteuserid,
                typeid AS notetypeid, data AS notedata  
        FROM ticket_notes WHERE ticketid = '$ticket_id'
        ) ticket_entries ORDER BY ticket_entries.id DESC
";
```

Comment: These tables got nothing to do with each other, except the `id` column, so I'm not sure if `JOIN` is the right answer. Anyways I executed your query and got an error: `#1052 - Column 'userid' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: that is easy to fix, corrected the answer. If these tables have nothing to do with each other, but they both have ticketId, then it's more natural to combine them with JOIN than with UNION. UNION is for combining homogenous results.

Comment: `#1052 - Column 'ticketid' in where clause is ambiguous`. After I fixed it I got another one: `#1054 - Unknown column 'ticket_entries.id' in 'order clause'`. I included sql structure in my post.

Comment: fixed too. Basically the rule is if you are joining tables then all fields with the same names should be prefixed with the table name. But there is a lot of fields in this query :) Also I believe you don't need to select these NULL fields actually, will remove them too.

Comment: One other thing: if not every ticket has a note, then there should be a LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Comment: I guess it's because there is no 1-1 relationship between your table: either there is more than one note possible for a ticket, or vice versa.

Comment: Yes, of course there is more than 1 note for the ticket. Why would I dedicate the whole table just for 1 record? =))

Comment: then what exactly do you want to achieve with your query? i.e. what question it answers?

Comment: E.g: you want to display all ticket entries + summary of notes per ticket (that's easy to achieve by grouping by ticketid) or something else entirely? Other question, is ticketid unique identifier or could there be same ticketid by different userid values? (then these tables should also be joined by userid)

Comment: Ah I think I get what you want.

Comment: In a simple way: I want all records from both `ticket_time_entries` and `ticket_notes` tables to be displayed on the page, but!!! ordered by column called `id`, that's it! =))

Comment: See the updated answer. You just had to adjust the column names, that's it.

Comment: Yep, works great. I just had to change `     ) ticket_entries ORDER BY id DESC`. Thank you so much. =)